# Suddenly can no longer deploy heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

After a month of successfully getting my app on Heroku, everything stopped working. No major changes. Google was mostly silent from my observations. Any help appreciated.

**the info**

```
heroku info
=== happyapp
Web URL:        http://happyapp.herokuapp.com/
Git Repo:       git@heroku.com:fitwit.git
Dynos:          0
Workers:        0
Repo size:      49M
Slug size:      84M
Stack:          cedar
Data size:      (empty)
Addons:         Basic Logging, MongoHQ MongoHQ Free, Basic Release Management, Shared Database 5MB
Owner:          heroku@mydomain.org
```

**the result**

```
%git push heroku master
Counting objects: 477, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (205/205), done.
Writing objects: 100% (367/367), 104.57 KiB, done.
Total 367 (delta 235), reused 223 (delta 145)

-----> Heroku receiving push
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:happyapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:happyapp.git'
```

Any other troubleshooting options?

Tim

Comment: Did you try the [official support](http://support.heroku.com/) yet?

Comment: Did you pick the Cedar stack on purpose ? In any case, it's still in beta so you might want to try the official support as suggested by Matthew

Comment: looking at status.heroku.com there were some push related issues lastnight, not sure if they are in the same time frame as when you were experiencing problems.

Comment: What sort of application are you deloying?  Have you just switched to Cedar?

Comment: No, this app has been working fine -- it is a Rails 3.1 app.

Comment: No, I looked at the official support, but didn't see anything off the shelf

Comment: I have logged a ticket with Heroku support for this as per the advice of Matthew Flaschen - I'll update this thread with the result

Comment: Received this from Heroku support: Hi,

You don't need the heroku gem in your Gemfile.

Your issue is likely that your application is not at the root of your repository. I.e. if you put it in /app or something, we'll not be able to detect it. The solution is to move it to the repo root.

Comment: I get similar error when i try to deploy diaspora to Heroku

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you fully add all files to be committed? I found that when this happened to me, it was because the commit I was pushing was not complete.

Run 'git status' to see if there are files not added to the commit, then run 'git add .' including the full stop at the end. A more thorough add would be 'git add -A' to include deleted files.

Following this commit and push as usual and see if this fixes the issue.

This worked for me.

Comment: I think this is the perfect solution. Mostly nothing wrong on heroku sode, if we missed some file to check in git and we faced this error. Thanks oddieis

Answer (score 0):

The response from Heroku support:

> Your issue is likely that your application is not at
>   the root of your repository. I.e. if you put it in /app or something,
>   we'll not be able to detect it. The solution is to move it to the repo
>   root

Putting my app in the repo root solved this problem for me.

---

I've been struggling with the same issue for 2 days now - perhaps some of my findings can help?

This [article](http://www.quora.com/Heroku/How-does-Heroku-work) states:

> Cedar apps are detected based on the presence of "Gemfile" for Ruby

My App certainly has a Gemfile, so I turned to the contents thereof, and ensured that the Gemfile contained:

```
gem "heroku"
```

I also read that the Cedar stack only supports Postgres, so I added:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

I'm completely new to Rails, GIT and Heroku, So I may have something else completely wrong...

My app is:

Ruby version              1.8.7
Rails version             3.1.0

Which I'm pretty sure is supposed to work on Cedar